# Conditional required not working in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2.2

I've got some code that was working ok in `jsf 1.2` but it's not in `jsf 2.2`. It's a conditional required field like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{gestorEmpleados.nombre}" id="textNombre" 
        required="#{gestorEmpleados.opARealizar=='insertar' or
                    gestorEmpleados.opARealizar=='modificar'}"
```

`gestorEmpleados` is a `SessionScoped bean`. I've got a breakpoint in the getter method for `opARealizar` property and it always returns `'eliminar'`, so the result for that conditional expression should be `'false'`. But there's always a validation error for the field.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you remove required alltogether? Maybe you have a validation on the entity

Comment: yeah, that would be a workaround, but I still would like to know why it is failing.

Comment: ups, you were right. The validation error was NOT for that field, but the message was referring to THAT field. I must have messed up the validation messages. Sorry for that and thanks for the tip.